# Which two numbers complete this number sequence?

Tags: number-sequence

Which two numbers complete this sequence?

7, 4, 2, 6, 9, (8), 7, 6, (5), __, __

Hint 1

> It's a **cool** number sequence.

Hint 2

> **Old** meets **modern** technology

Hint 3

> The sequence ends.

Comment: Did you bracket sixth and ninth element on purpose?

Comment: Yes, the sequence ends! This is important!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Taking all of your hints into account, I come to the conclusion that the answer is

> 4 and 9

Explanation:

> Some of the numbers in the sequence are bracketed. I think that those are the numbers that need to be skipped to construct the classic 'Haus vom Nikolaus' (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497342/das-ist-das-haus-vom-nikolaus-and-euler-cycle) on a smartphone's numeric keypad (second hint: "**Old** meets **modern** technology"). But up until now it's just an assumption, because you didn't answer my question (yet).
>  Why do I think of the "Haus vom Nikolaus" (house of Nikolaus)? Well, that's because of your first hint "It is a **cool** number sequence puzzle". The house of Nikolaus (or Santa Claus) is located at a very cold place on planet earth.
>  To support my point of view, I created a gif illustrating what I mean and how it (seemingly) fits perfectly.
>  [image]

Comment: how the *hell* did you come up with this?? That's amazing...

Comment: @user477343 Thank you :-) Well ... all the given numbers lie between 2 (minimum) and 9 (maximum). Some of them are bracketed (which seemed quite interesting) and this sequence is *limited*! Toying with some ideas and taking all the given hints into account finally led me to this conclusion :-)

Comment: @AndréDalwigk I don't know that you guys are from this world or another world......

Comment: @AndréDalwigk You. Are. Just. Awesome!!!